# Redux store property gets nested into itself on update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having this issue where my `props` are ending up looking like this (on console.log):

```
{
    fetchRoles: f(),
    roles:
        roles: ["Admin", "Manager"],
}
```

As you can see, somewhere in my code I'm making a mistake that causes the `roles` prop to get nested into itself, which would force me into doing `const { roles } = this.props.roles;` in order to retrieve my data (which works BTW).

I've looked around for help but not many people seem to have run into this issue (I'm just getting started with redux).

Below you can see my files:

`rolesReducer.js`:

```
import { FETCH_ROLES } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  roles: [],
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  const { roles } = action;
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_ROLES:
      return {
        ...state, //also tried ...state.roles and same issue.
        roles,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

`rolesActions.js`:

```
import { FETCH_ROLES } from "./types";

const roles = ["SuperAdmin"];

export function fetchRoles() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({
      type: FETCH_ROLES,
      roles,
    });
  };
}
```

`reducers/index.js` (root reducer):

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import rolesReducer from "./rolesReducer";
import roleMembersReducer from "./roleMembersReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  roles: rolesReducer,
  roleMembers: roleMembersReducer,
});
```

`PermissionsManager.jsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { fetchRoles } from "../redux/actions/rolesActions";

import RoleContainer from "./RoleContainer";

class PermissionsManager extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchRoles();
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    const { roles } = this.props.roles;
    return (
      <Container>
        {roles.map((role) => {
          return <RoleContainer key={role} role={role} />;
        })}
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    roles: state.roles,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchRoles })(PermissionsManager);
```

**Edit 1 - Adding reducer log:**

As suggested, I logged the reducer, specifically `state` and `action`:

`state`:

```
{
    roles: [],
}
```

`action`:

```
{
    roles: ["Admin", "Manager"],
    type: "FETCH_ROLES",
}
```

No duplication or abnormal structures I believe.

Comment: Your code appears correct at first glance. You're going to need to debug manually unfortunately. Put a console log at the top of your reducer and make sure the state and action are what you expect.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. Just updated the question with the logs. They look OK to me, that is nothing looks out of place.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a runnable example?

Comment: Hi Shadab, thanks for lending a hand. I could try to provide a simplified project but this component is coupled with and depends on data that is confidential to my company. The answer provided by @maioman did work and my only concern left is expressed on the comment I left on their answer (basically is that a solution or a workaround to an anti-pattern or bad practice I made).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to shape the store like you're asking is to flatten roles in `rolesReducer.js`,
you can do so storing the received array directly in the partial state:

`initialState` would need to look like

```
const initialState = []
```

and in the switch statement

```
 case FETCH_ROLES:
  return roles
```

Comment: Hi maioman, I made the changes you suggested and it worked! I have a follow up question though. Is this a solution or a workaround to a deeper underlying issue in my store, reducers or actions? I guess what I'm trying to understand is if I'm making something wrong which forces me to do this. Also, does declaring `initialState` as an array come with any considerations? Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: From a technical point of view your initial setup was ok, from what I understand the issue you had was just about shaping the store to avoid duplicated nested object property named  "roles". Declaring initialState as array comes with no considerations.